# get mvn dependency version with cli

Tags: maven, command-line-interface

I'm trying to get the Version of one Artifact via cli as described here:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html

```
RESULT+=$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -Dartifact=$GROUP_ID:$ARTIFACT_ID -q -DforceStdout)
echo "$RESULT"
```

The Problem is:

> "Note: Should respect the Maven format, i.e. groupId:artifactId[:version]. The latest version of the artifact will be used when no version is specified."

So I always get the last possible Version as an answer.
But I need to know, which Version is used and not what could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way via dependency:list Plugin and grep

```sh
ARTIFACT_ID = artefactId

RESULT += $(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:list -DincludeArtifactIds=$ARTIFACT_ID -DforceStdout -DoutputScope=false | grep $ARTIFACT_ID | sed 's/.*jar:\(.*\):.*/\1/')

echo $RESULT
```